# Unity Game App runs fine on editor but crashes at startup on Android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, crash, startup

edit
new log error from google play console with symbols uploaded
Exceptions
#555 pc 0000000000516aa4 /data/app/com.BananaBananaGamesStudio.PandaInLove-uwkWI1KD8Ky8mqZVu3tIrQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: f906d698b5739e4c9b6fd97129c65207b1de60a9)
Native crash of com.BananaBananaGamesStudio.PandaInLove
at libc.scudo::Allocator<scudo::AndroidConfig, &(scudo_malloc_postinit)>::allocate(unsigned long, scudo::Chunk::Origin, unsigned long, bool)(AndroidConfig, &:4)
Native crash of com.BananaBananaGamesStudio.PandaInLove
#555 pc 0000000000516aa4 /data/app/com.BananaBananaGamesStudio.PandaInLove-iIA-AL9fmIJZKfg8FD7WXA==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (BuildId: f906d698b5739e4c9b6fd97129c65207b1de60a9)
Native crash of com.BananaBananaGamesStudio.PandaInLove
#01 pc 00347a1a /data/media/0/Android/data/com.BananaBananaGamesStudio.PandaInLove/files/il2cpp/Metadata/global-metadata.dat
Native crash of com.BananaBananaGamesStudio.PandaInLove

I'm struggling for about two weeks on this:
I made a game on the last months and it was running fine both on editor and on my Android phone.
I made more levels and implemented Unity Ads with no errors on the editor.
But now it crashs on the first seconds at my Android device. But stills runs fine on the editor.
With Unity Android Logcat I got this:

> 01/30 23:01:46.457 31856 31856 Error Zygote accessInfo : 0 01/30
> 23:01:47.137 31856 31869 Error CRASH *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
> *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** 01/30 23:01:47.137 31856 31869 Error CRASH Version '2020.3.23f1 (c5d91304a876)', Build type 'Release',
> Scripting Backend 'il2cpp', CPU 'armeabi-v7a' 01/30 23:01:47.137 31856
> 31869 Error CRASH Build fingerprint:
> 'samsung/j5lteub/j5lte:6.0.1/MMB29M/J500MUBU1BRD1:user/release-keys'
> 01/30 23:01:47.137 31856 31869 Error CRASH Revision: '5' 01/30
> 23:01:47.137 31856 31869 Error CRASH ABI: 'arm' 01/30 23:01:47.137
> 31856 31869 Error CRASH Timestamp: 2022-01-30 23:01:47-0300 01/30
> 23:01:47.137 31856 31869 Error CRASH pid: 31856, tid: 31869, name:
> UnityMain  >>> com.BananaBananaGamesStudio.PandaInLove <<< 01/30
> 23:01:47.137 31856 31869 Error CRASH uid: 10172 01/30 23:01:47.137
> 31856 31869 Error CRASH signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR),
> fault addr 0xb2d5cff8 01/30 23:01:47.137 31856 31869 Error CRASH
> r0  9ef603b0  r1  b7c46bc8  r2  b7c46bc8  r3  b2d5d03e 01/30
> 23:01:47.137 31856 31869 Error CRASH     r4  9ef48fb0  r5  0000011e
> r6  b2d5d03f  r7  0000008f 01/30 23:01:47.137 31856 31869 Error CRASH
> r8  b2d5d038  r9  99068f84  r10 99083a1c  r11 b2d5d010 01/30
> 23:01:47.137 31856 31869 Error CRASH     ip  9900ca7c  sp  b2d5d010
> lr  9de33824  pc  9de33660 01/30 23:01:47.137 31856 31869 Error CRASH
> 01/30 23:01:47.137 31856 31869 Error CRASH backtrace: 01/30
> 23:01:47.137 31856 31869 Error CRASH       #00 pc 002fb660
> /data/app/com.BananaBananaGamesStudio.PandaInLove-1/lib/arm/libil2cpp.so
> (BuildId: b5c43ddd04c71984469ca752577c033162526da7) 01/30 23:01:47.267
> 31856 31869 Error CRASH Tombstone written to:
> /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.BananaBananaGamesStudio.PandaInLove/files/tombstone_02
> 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime FATAL EXCEPTION:
> UnityMain 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime Process:
> com.BananaBananaGamesStudio.PandaInLove, PID: 31856 01/30 23:01:47.267
> 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION
> [UnityMain] 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime Unity
> version     : 2020.3.23f1 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error
> AndroidRuntime Device model      : samsung SM-J500M 01/30 23:01:47.267
> 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime Device fingerprint:
> samsung/j5lteub/j5lte:6.0.1/MMB29M/J500MUBU1BRD1:user/release-keys
> 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime Build Type
> : Release 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime
> Scripting Backend : IL2CPP 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error
> AndroidRuntime ABI               : armeabi-v7a 01/30 23:01:47.267
> 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime Strip Engine Code : true 01/30
> 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime  01/30 23:01:47.267
> 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime Caused by: java.lang.Error: *** ***
> *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime Version '2020.3.23f1
> (c5d91304a876)', Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp', CPU
> 'armeabi-v7a' 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime
> Build fingerprint:
> 'samsung/j5lteub/j5lte:6.0.1/MMB29M/J500MUBU1BRD1:user/release-keys'
> 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime Revision: '5'
> 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime ABI: 'arm' 01/30
> 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime Timestamp: 2022-01-30
> 23:01:47-0300 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime pid:
> 31856, tid: 31869, name: UnityMain  >>>
> com.BananaBananaGamesStudio.PandaInLove <<< 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856
> 31869 Error AndroidRuntime uid: 10172 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869
> Error AndroidRuntime signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault
> addr 0xb2d5cff8 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime
> r0  9ef603b0  r1  b7c46bc8  r2  b7c46bc8  r3  b2d5d03e 01/30
> 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime     r4  9ef48fb0  r5
> 0000011e  r6  b2d5d03f  r7  0000008f 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869
> Error AndroidRuntime     r8  b2d5d038  r9  99068f84  r10 99083a1c  r11
> b2d5d010 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime     ip
> 9900ca7c  sp  b2d5d010  lr  9de33824  pc  9de33660 01/30 23:01:47.267
> 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime  01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error
> AndroidRuntime backtrace: 01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error
> AndroidRuntime       #00 pc 002fb660
> /data/app/com.BananaBananaGamesStudio.PandaInLove-1/lib/arm/libil2cpp.so
> (BuildId: b5c43ddd04c71984469ca752577c033162526da7) 01/30 23:01:47.267
> 31856 31869 Error AndroidRuntime  01/30 23:01:47.267 31856 31869 Error
> AndroidRuntime    at libil2cpp.0x2fb660(Native Method)

If someone can point a light to help myself I can't thank you enough.
More Details:
Unity Version: 2020.3.23f1
IL2CPP
NET Standard 2.0
Minimum API 19 (4.4 KitKat)
Target API 30 (11.0)
My Android Device 6.01 (Marshmallow)
ARMv7 and ARM64 both checked
Already tryed with minimum and target to Marshmallow without sucess. Same results: crash on startup, not get into splash screen.
Interesting facts: After clicking ok to the message "App crashed", the app still running on background. And testing on a 11.0 Samsung Android phone results in a black screen. Also the aab uploaded to google play store shows mostly black screens on the lab test and few crashs on few devices.
I'm redoing from zero the project and slowly adding piece by piece again, and compiling , testing and recompiling every single addition, but has been a pain in the ass. I also did add the Ads system and it is working on the zero-project, so I believe has nothing to do with it.
I'm using bolt to visual script a lot, and also did an AOT pre build with the same (bad) results...
Any help in where to go from here is much appreciated. I'm new to C# and Unity but I really try hard before asking for help. Thanks.

Comment: Try changing your Unity version

Comment: Try netStandart 4x , update your sdk and ndk files if nessecarily, change your supported graphic api settings under project settings (if checked auto just uncheck & add manually GL and Vulkan api's) , also maybe should check any experimental features are checked under your project settings and uncheck all after all of these rebuild your project and test again. Finally change your Unity Editor version or try to run resolver. I hope one of these solve your problem..

Comment: gonna try it. Thanks a lot !